# Error when adding new fields in tree view odoo 10.0

Tags: treeview, odoo-10

I want to add new attributes in product tree view but an error happened when I started my server and updated my addons look like :

> ParseError: "Erreur lors de la validation de la contrainte
>
> ```
> Mod\xe8le non trouv\xe9 : product.template
>
> Contexte de l'erreur :
> Vue `productTree`
> [view_id: 752, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: 308]
> None" while parsing /opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/addons/test_tuto/views/views.xml:3, near
> <record id="view_product_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
>       <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
>       <field name="name">productTree</field>
>       <field name="model">product.template</field>
>       <field name="type">tree</field>
>       <field name="arch" type="xml">
>         <xpath expr="/tree/field[@name='categ_id']" position="after">
>           <field name="calories"/>
>           <field name="servingsize"/>
>           <field name="lastupdated"/>
>         </xpath>
>       </field>
> </record>
> ```

Here is my view source code,

```xml
<record id="view_product_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
      <field name="name">productTree</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
      <field name="type">tree</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/tree/field[@name='categ_id']" position="after">
          <field name="calories"/>
          <field name="servingsize"/>
          <field name="lastupdated"/>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
```

And here is the python code I added 3 fields in my class inherit from product template class.

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api

class test_tuto(models.Model):
    _inhirit = 'product.template'

    calories = fields.Integer("Calories")
    servingsize = fields.Float("Serving size")
    lastupdated = fields.Datetime('Last Updated')
```

as you request here you are my manifest.py file
I write my xml code in views.xml file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "Test_tuto",

    'summary': """
        Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
        subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

Comment: Can you show the manifest?

Comment: OK !  i edited the post, you can see my manifest file ! i writed my xml code in views.xml file

Comment: You need to add `product` in depends.

Comment: Correct `_inhirit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing your *"xpath"* like this

add '**product**' in depends

```
'depends': ['base','product'],


       <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='categ_id']" position="after">
          <field name="calories"/>
          <field name="servingsize"/>
          <field name="lastupdated"/>
        </xpath>
```

Comment: thanks this error gone but what about "'calories' field doesn't exit", but it exist in table in database and in database structer in odoo configuration